# Is it possible to add arbitrary data to an ObjectifiedElement instance?

Tags: python, lxml

I've set up a custom [namespace lookup dictionary](http://lxml.de/element_classes.html#namespace-class-lookup) in order to map elements in XML files to subclasses of [`ObjectifiedElement`](http://lxml.de/objectify.html). Now, I want to add some data to instances of these classes. But due to the way `ObjectifiedElement` works, adding an attribute will result in an element being added to the element tree, which is not what I want. More importantly, this doesn't work for all Python types; for example, it is not possible to create an attribute of the `list` type.

This seems to be possible by subclassing `ElementBase` instead, but that would imply losing the features provided by `ObjectifiedElement`. You could say I only need the *read part* of `ObjectifiedElement`. I suppose I can add a `__getattr__` to my subclasses to simulate this, but I was hoping there was another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with having `__getattr__()` simply forward to etree's `find()`:

```
class SomewhatObjectifiedElement(etree.ElementBase):
    nsmap = {'ns': 'http://www.my.org/namespace'}

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.find('ns:' + name, self.nsmap)
```

This will only return the first element if there are several matching, unlike `ObjectifiedElement`'s behaviour, but it suffices for my application (mostly it can be only a single match, otherwise, I use `findall()`).